# Select only specific polygon of the feature, OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-3

[image: OpenLayers]

A Feature is made of several parts, how do i select just one of them on mouse click in openLayers?
By default the whole feature gets selected.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to create a new source containing features with single polygon geometry.  Give them a parent property if you need to access the original feature.  For example

```
mainSource.on('addfeature', function(event) {
  var geometry = event.feature.getGeometry();
  if (geometry.getType() == 'MultiPolygon') {
    geometry.getPolygons().forEach(function(polygon) {
      splitSource.addFeature(new Feature({
        geometry: polygon,
        parent: event.feature
    });
  } else {
    splitSource.addFeature(event.feature);
  }
});
```